# Find exponential function given two points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

$f(x) = ar^x $ given that $r > 0$.

I'm given two points ($3$, $\frac{8}{9}$) and ($4$, $\frac{16}{27}$).

My textbook then says  $$r = \frac{\frac{16}{27}}{\frac{8}{9}}$$

Why does this work? I can't figure out why $y_2/y_1 = r$.

There's some other similar questions asked on this site but the answers are too complicated, using integrals and natural logarithms and such to explain something this simple.

Comment: Just plug in the two sets of values for x and y (= f(x)) to obtain two equations. Divide one equation by the other to get the answer.

Comment: @Mick why does dividing get you the answer?

Comment: After division, the “y-side” will give the fraction quoted and the “a & r – side” will become r, after the cancellations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Mick said, all you're doing is solving the system
$$ar^3=\frac89$$
$$ar^4=\frac {16}{27}$$

If you divide the second equation by the first, you get
$$\frac{ar^4}{ar^3}=\frac{\frac{16}{27}}{\frac{8}{9}}$$
$$\Rightarrow r=\frac{\frac{16}{27}}{\frac{8}{9}}$$

Comment: I only know of the substitution and elimination method. Is division another way to get it done?

Comment: @user1534664 Yes.

Comment: @user1534664 Substitution works very similarly here: $ar^4=r(ar^3)=r \left ( \frac{8}{9} \right ) = \frac{16}{27}$.